# Update DB schema without using migrations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, schema, rake

I'm looking for a command that updates the schema automatically, without having to write migrations files.

For example, when I start a Java Hibernate app, with some configuration, the DB schema is automatically built and updated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible with ActiveRecord but if you don't mind changing ORM you could look into [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org) instead.

With DM you define the 'properties' (attributes) of your models in the model code itself and then you can simply run rake db:automigrate to update the database's schema, e.g.

```
class Blog
  property :title,    String
  property :body,     Text
  property :user_id,  Integer, :required => true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) you can

An example (with sqlite, but it's the same with other adapters)

First the normal start:

```
require "sequel"
DB = Sequel.sqlite(DB_NAME)

# create an items table
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Float :price
end

# [....]

require "sequel"
DB = Sequel.sqlite('test.db')

# create an items table
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Float :price
end
```

Later you can modify the table:

```
DB.add_column :items, :valid_from, Date
```

The following modifications are possible (perhaps there are more):

- add_column
- add_index
- create_view
- drop_column
- drop_index
- drop_table
- drop_view
- rename_table
- rename_column
- set_column_default
- set_column_type

---

In combination with `rake` you could do something like:

```
require "rake"
require "sequel"

task :connect do
  DB = Sequel.sqlite('test.db')
end

desc 'create an items table'
task :create_items => :connect do
  DB.create_table :items do
    primary_key :id
    String :name
    Float :price
  end
end

task :add_dates_to_items => :connect do
  #check if items exist is missing
  DB.add_column :items, :valid_from, Date
end
```

Remark: Migrations are a help to avoid wrong sequences of schema modifications. With Migrations you can define the correct sequence. The actual status is stored and you can downgrade.